# Concatenating Values Within SQL XML field

Tags: sql, xml

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 which has an XML field.  The field contains arrays (the number of elements is not constant) in the following format:

```
<values>
    <value>A</value>
    <value>B</value>
    <value>C</value>
    <value>D</value>
</values>
```

and I would like to turn it into a varchar like this:

```
'A;B;C;D'
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT myField.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
FROM   myTable
```

which creates 'ABCD' but I don't know how to delimit it (In the real case they are not single character values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (id int,myField XML)

INSERT INTO @myTable(id,myField) VALUES(1,'<values>
    <value>A</value>
    <value>B</value>
    <value>C</value>
    <value>D</value>
</values>')


;WITH xmltable
AS
(
    SELECT id, myField.v.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS myField
    FROM @myTable 
    CROSS APPLY myField.nodes('/values/value') AS myField(v)
)

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';' + myField 
                  FROM xmltable t2 
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.id  
                  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS myField
FROM xmltable t1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: That works thanks, I was hoping for something simpler but I'm beginning to think it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of a hack to achieve this...

```
SELECT REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                   CAST([myField] As NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
                   '<values><value>', 
                   ''), 
               '</value></values>', 
               ''), 
           '</value><value>', 
           ';'
       ) As [Hacked] 
FROM   [myTable]
```

...but it makes me feel a bit dirty.  There has to be a better way.